# Cannot connect to my Digital Ocean K8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, devops, digital-ocean

I'm trying to connect to my kubernetes cluster on Digital Ocean using

```
doctl kubernetes cluster kubeconfig save cluster_name
```

> the output of this command tells me that: Notice: Adding cluster
> credentials to kubeconfig file found in
> "/home/akhateeb22/.kube/config" Notice: Setting current-context to
> name_of_context

which is seem to be okay
but when i do `kubectl get nodes` i still get my local node not the Digital Ocean one
I check contexts i have, i got just one which is the local.
how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you need to change the context of your kubectl command.

first, run the command `kubectl config get-contexts` to list all the contexts you have in the *.kube/config* file, then change the context to the correct cluster with `kubectl config use-context <context name>`